# How to check and install .net C# application using NSIS Installer

Tags: windows, winforms, nsis, autorun

I want to check whether the particular driver say xxx is installed or not in windows while installing my c# form application.If that driver is not installed i should run the driver executable first.

Now,I have a NSI script that check the DotNetFramework is installed or not using DotNetSearch.nsh.But i dont know how to check the xxx driver supplied by vendor.

Comment: It depend from driver. Usually checks appropriate registry keys or driver file existence by path.

Comment: can you post the code snippet for this..it will be helpful..

Comment: There are multiple types of drivers, telling us the name of it would help...

Answer (score 0):

What is the name of this driver? What kind of driver is it? Does the vendor provide any documentation or support?

There are multiple driver types on Windows; Non-PNP/NT4 style drivers are registered in the same place as NT services. PNP and filter drivers can probably be detected with the Setup and/or CM APIs and you might have to use network related APIs if this is a NDIS driver...